# How to check if DateTime difference exceeds a threshold in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$dt1 = new DateTime($myObject['ModifyTime']);
$dtNow = new DateTime();
$timeDifference = date_diff($dt1,$dtNow);
```

I need to check if DateTime dt1 is older than now by >300 minutes. How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the difference is greater than 5 hours:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime($myObject['ModifyTime']);
$dtNow = new DateTime();
$timeDifference = date_diff($dt1,$dtNow);
if ($timeDifference->h > 5) {
  // greater than 300 minutes
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eZrIu9)

See [`DatInterval::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for more information on DateInterval formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can do it purely on timestamps also:

```
<?php

$dt1 = new DateTime($myObject['ModifyTime']);
$now = time();

var_dump($now - $dt1->getTimestamp() >= 300 * 60); // should return true

?>
```

Timestamp is represented in seconds (from 1970-01-01). So 300 minutes is 300 x 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between timestamps is in seconds so just divide it by 60 for minutes and so on

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-03-12 11:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-03-12 16:00');
// difference in seconds
$interval = datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp();

// difference in minutes
$interval = interval / 60;

// difference in hours
$interval = interval / (60 * 60);
```